# Garbage Collector is not logging anything and we have memory issues

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Apparently we have a problem with the Garbage Collector in our Java (8) application (in PROD, UAT, TEST). In the logs (I mean in general application/POD logs) we see error messages related to 'long gc', and 'out of memory' due to heap space. Also, I see that in the PODs the memory usage never goes down, grows or stays, until it reaches a peak and dies. Locally I did heap dump and GC log analysis and everything looked normal (the GC was running and freeing up space. I tried to put the configuration to get logs from the GC in TEST environment, the fact is that no log was generated! Yes, the file was generated, with what I will now show below, but later, and despite the fact that we ran processes, nothing new appeared in the file. I do not understand if it may not be running, if I used the wrong parameters (enabling the logging) or how to face this. Thank you.

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 65789716k(2386800k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:InitialHeapSize=1052635456 -XX:MaxHeapSize=16842167296 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 300032K, used 20603K [0x0000000671600000, 0x0000000686480000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 257536K, 8% used [0x0000000671600000,0x0000000672a1ed38,0x0000000681180000)
  from space 42496K, 0% used [0x0000000683b00000,0x0000000683b00000,0x0000000686480000)
  to   space 42496K, 0% used [0x0000000681180000,0x0000000681180000,0x0000000683b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 685568K, used 0K [0x00000003d4200000, 0x00000003fdf80000, 0x0000000671600000)
  object space 685568K, 0% used [0x00000003d4200000,0x00000003d4200000,0x00000003fdf80000)
 Metaspace       used 3126K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 311K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: You don't tell which jvm version you are using. Check documentation for that jre, you might be able to tweak the gc so it's collecting more eagerly.  Otherwise you will have to increase max heap memory.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Thanks for the reply. We use Java 8, now I add it to the question, is that data sufficient in this regard?
Regarding what you say, I am going to look for it, but the fact that no log appears still generates doubts. Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.  There may be techniques like object pooling that can alleviate your problem, but we won't know unless we can see your code.  Read "How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Which specific version of Java 8 are you using? Earlier Java 8 versions (before 1.8.0_191) did not play nicely with containers...